# Firebase: retrieve value of class that implements Map<K, V>

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

Assume I have data class:

```
class MyDataClass {
    ...
    public Map<String, Object> properties = HashMap()
}

// later
MyDataClass data = snapshot.getValue(MyDataClass.class);
```

After running this code data.properties contains all the data that exists under the `properties` key in the given snapshot.

For some reason I want to change type of `properties` field to my custom Map implementation:

```
class MyMap implements Map<String, Object> { ... }

class MyDataClass {
    ...
    public MyMap properties = MyMap()
}

// later
MyDataClass data = snapshot.getValue(MyDataClass.class);
```

After running this code data.properties no data.

I wonder if it is even possible to retrieve data to custom map implementation?

UPD: JSON i try to read

```
{
  items: {
    "id": {
      "name": "name",
      "properties": {
        "simpleProp1": "value1",
        "simpleProp2": "value2",
        "simpleProp3": "value3",
        "complexProp1": {
          "subPop1": "subVal1"
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you use MyMap class ? You can directly add MyDataClass like below `public class MyDataClass {
    public HashMap<String,String> myData;

    public HashMap<String, String> getMyData() {
        return myData;
    }

    public void setMyData(HashMap<String, String> myData) {
        this.myData = myData;
    }
}
`

Comment: Seems You misunderstood my question. I NEED to use my custom Map implementation for "properties". And I wonder why firebase snapshot.getValue() method doesn't populate it with data?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @AlexMamo No errors. It seems to me that firebase simply do not "understand" that MyMap is a custom Map implementation and search for properties to populate data. Since there is no properties in MyMap firebase skip it.

Comment: Why you need a custom implmentation? Maybe we'll find another method.

Comment: Just use as i give PoJo class may be halp

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank You! But I already use some workaround for this problem, and want to find answer for this particular question - can we use custom Map implementations with firebase-database or not? Maybe there is some annotation for this case?

Comment: Please update the question to include a snippet of the JSON you've read on the snapshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I add sample JSON to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Firebase will be able to work with your custom `Map` implementation directly. As such, you might consider adding a simple data class instead:

```
class MyDataJSON {
    public MyDataJSON() { }
    public String name;
    public Map<String, Object> properties;
}

class MyDataClass {
    MyDataClass(MyDataJSON json) { ... }
    ...
}
```

then use it to construct your `MyDataClass` object:

```
MyDataJSON json = snapshot.getValue(MyDataJSON.class);
MyDataClass data = MyDataClass(json);
```

I know, far from perfect, but at least you gain complete control over the database *unmarshalling* process (and corresponding properties types).

Comment: @abond Nice ;) BTW, don't forget to upvote/accept my answer so we can mark this question as closed. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me:

```
public static class MyDataClass {
    public String name;
    public Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyDataClass{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", properties=" + properties +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And then:

```
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   MyDataClass data = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyDataClass.class);
                   System.out.println(data);
               }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
```

Prints:

> MyDataClass{name='name', properties={simpleProp2=value2, simpleProp1=value1, complexProp1={subPop1=subVal1}, simpleProp3=value3}}

Comment: I think he wants to use his custom `Map` implementation for the `properties` field instead (i.e. his `MyMap` class).

Comment: Thank you Frank! This code works for me, too. But what I want is to replace new HashMap<String,Object>(); with my own implementation of Map<K, V> interface.  For testing purpose You can create class that implement Map interface by just delegating all of its method calls to private HashMap property.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This took lots of digging into [the SDK code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java). The custom Map class won't work. Our deserialization in that case doesn't realize it's a collection and thus treats it as a bean class (serializing the individual properties/fields) instead of the items in the collection.